# How to keep an object's reference when using UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

The problem I'm facing is probably some lack of understanding on the concept of reusable cells. I have, let's say, 30 rows to be created and each of them has a UISwitch.

When I toggle one of the switches, it's behavior should affect the other 29. The point is: as far as I know, iOS doesn't create all of them at once, but rather wait to reuse the cells when the TableView is scrolled up and down.

How can I keep a copy of those reused objects and tell iOS to set the proper value to the switches?

I've thought on having the cells appended to a [UISwitch] but I can't manage to have all the 30 cells in there, look:

```
...

var switches = [UISwitch]()

...

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Field10Cell", for: indexPath) as! Field10TableViewCell

    ...

    //cell.value is a UISwitch
    if !switches.contains(cell.value) {
        switches.append(cell.value)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: "When I toggle one of the switches, it's behavior should affect the other 29." Can you please explain this more?

Comment: let's say I toggle switch one. on it's 'onvaluechanged' I want to disable all the other 29 switches, which I can't because I don't have them instances yet (I guess)

Comment: You are thinking the wrong way. If all switches are supposed to have the same state if one switch is toggled, declare one boolean property to keep the current state and an `IBAction`. Connect the button in the cell to the action. If a switch changes the value, update the boolean property, reload the table view and set the state of the switches in cellForRow accordingly.

Comment: @vadian where should I declare that variable? In the cell or in the tableview class?

Comment: In the controller.

Comment: @vadian I will try do it, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a set which stores the indexes of the cells whose switches have been pressed.

```
var activeSwitches = Set<IndexPath>()
```

Whenever a user presses the switch on a cell, you store it on the set like this:

```
activeSwitches.insert(indexPath)
```

If you need to check if a switch was activated, just check if its container cell's indexPath is in active switches like so:

```
if activeSwitches.contains(indexPath) {
    // do something
}
```

In order to know when a user pressed a specific switch I recommend the folliwing:

1. In cellForRowAtIndexPath save the current indexPath into your Field10TableViewCell.
2. Create a protocol on Field10TableViewCell and add a delegate.

   ```
   protocol Field10Delegate {
       func didChangeSwitch(value: Bool, indexPath: IndexPath)
   }

   class Field10TableViewCell {
       var delegate: Field10Delegate?
       var indexPath: IndexPath?
       @IBOutlet weak var fieldSwitch: UISwitch! // Can't use 'switch' as a variable name

       @IBAction func switchValueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
           if let indexPath = indexPath {
               delegate?.didChangeSwitch(value: sender.isOn, indexPath: indexPath)
           }
       }
   ```
3. When you create a cell, set the view controller as a delegate

   ```
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Field10Cell", for: indexPath) as! Field10TableViewCell
   cell.delegate = self
   cell.indexPath = indexPath
   ```
4. Make your view controller comply with the protocol:

   ```
   extension ViewController: Field10Delegate {
       /* Whenever a switch is pressed on any cell, this delegate will
          be called. This is a good place also to trigger a update to
          your UI if it has to respond to switch changes.
        */
       func didChangeSwitch(value: Bool, indexPath: IndexPath) {
           if value {
               activeSwitches.insert(indexPath)
           } else {
               activeSwitches.remove(indexPath)
           }
           updateUI()
       }
   }
   ```

With the above, at any point you will know which switches are active or not and you can process the dequeued cells with this information.

Comment: this is a great answer, thank you! i've enjoyed your blog as well :)

Comment: `== true` is redundant. `if value {`

Comment: And btw no need to add an IBOutlet for the switch. Just use the sender instead. UISwitch has no value property. You should use its isOn property. `sender.isOn`

Comment: I'm glad to help @Rob! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the corrections @LeoDabus! I was coding by memory, prone to some mistakes :-/

Comment: @FelipeFerri you forgot to remove the fieldSwitch  outlet

Comment: oh well I just assumed Rob would need an outlet inside the cell for other things, such as assigning it a value when creating a new cell...

Comment: @FelipeFerri usually shouldn't need one. but it wouldn't hurt :)

Comment: Generally you are strongly discouraged from keeping an array/set of index paths. Index paths can change without calling `cellForRow`, for example when you are implementing row reordering via drag&drop.

Comment: Good point. Maybe storing a pointer to the activated switch would be better?